# How to notice that a message sent to dialogflow is longer than 256 characters?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I made a facebook chatbot with dialogflow. My problem is that some users write messages to my bot that are longer than 256 characters.

Dialogflow just throws an error that the character size exceeded. As the result, the user has no answer.

I don't expect dialogflow to process the input. I just want to get this information in my backend, so I can send the user to the live chat.

Please, say me it is possible (and how ;) ).

Comment: if you are having webhook you can trim text to just 256 and then send it to dialogflow

Comment: My webhook is called by dialogflow. Facebook sends the text to dialogflow and the error occures. Unfortunately, it doesn't reach my webhook...

Comment: do you have oneclick integration ?

Comment: Yes. I used the dialogflow one click integration.

Comment: in this case you want get the string sent from facebook, if you are using custom webhook you can manage string length

Comment: So, a custom webhook between facebook and dialogflow is the only way to handle this issue?

Comment: yes, with custom webhook you will get first request in your server and then you can modify and send it to the Dialogflow

Comment: Okay. That's more effortful than I hoped. But it is a solution. Thank you much, @Nikhil Savaliya!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By following this you will be able to set the custom webhook => [Webhook setup](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/webhook-setup)

Make this server live with [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) with temporary later on you can migrate to your server

Now you will get `event` in which you will find your message sent from facebook messenger.

you can write simple JS function to send only 256 character to [Dialogflow Functions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow)

`str.substring(0,255)`

and send it to `detectIntent` in dialogflow function.